# Keyframe Animations not in sync

Tags: css, css-animations

Works correctly on my local filesystem, not from a server. It is starting out of sync for some reason. Thanks for any help. Only vendor prefixed for WebKit. Tested in Chrome 26.Demo: http://cssdesk.com/jjqKK

HTML:

```
<ul class="slides">
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><span class="caption">Image 1</span></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><span class="caption">Image 2</span></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><span class="caption">Image 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.slides{
  position: relative;
    background: #000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.slides li{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-animation: slideshow 9s linear infinite;
}
ul.slides.clickpause:active li{
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
}
ul.slides li:nth-child(1){ -webkit-animation-delay: 0s; }
ul.slides li:nth-child(2){  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s; }
ul.slides li:nth-child(3){  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s; }
@-webkit-keyframes slideshow{
0%{
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
3%{
    opacity: 1;
}
30%{
    opacity: 1;
 }
33%{
    opacity: 0;
 }
34%{
    z-index: 1;
 }
100%{
    opacity: 0;
 }
}
ul.slides li img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}
ul.slides li span{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.8);
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px
}
```

Demo: http://cssdesk.com/jjqKK

Please no answers that use JavaScript. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean it 'flashes' the third slide, before the animation starts?

Comment: Looks good on my Chrome. Maybe there was a flash in the beginning, I cannot say.

Comment: @Chris No, it's not in sync here. e.g., slide 1 shows for 3s, while slide 2 shows for less than 1s; then there's a delay after Slide 3 before slide 1 appears again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your animations might not always start at the same time.

I've found that negative delays work really well with keeping things in sync. With this technique, each animation will load at the same time, but some parts start *in the past*. Check out the jsbin example:

http://jsbin.com/EreYIdE/2/edit

**edited** to add example inline:

```css
ul {
  background: #000;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

li {
  height: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  width: inherit;
  
  -webkit-animation: slideshow 9s linear infinite;
  animation: slideshow 9s linear infinite;
}

li:nth-child(1) { 
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9s; 
  animation-delay: -9s; 
}

li:nth-child(2) { 
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6s;
  animation-delay: -6s;
}

li:nth-child(3) { 
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3s; 
  animation-delay: -3s; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideshow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slideshow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

span {
  background: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
    <span>Image 1</span>
 
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
    <span>Image 2</span>
 
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
    <span>Image 3</span>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: very helpful, just what I needed to solve a similar problem (images slide in/out). negative delay values *&* the z-index were essential. thank you helloworld!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to add an animation trigger using **javascript**

[Javascript demo](http://jsfiddle.net/asantarissy/zFVC2)

```
window.onload = function (){ }
```

or
[jQuery demo](http://jsfiddle.net/asantarissy/zFVC2/1/)

```
$(window).load(function(){})
```

as **CSS3 animations** and **transitions** start immediately before document load.

Comment: The idea here is to be JS-free.

Comment: From what I can tell, this is the only way to synchronize CSS animations. At least the JS is very minimal. The only other alternatives would involve a lot more JS (adding/removing classes and using transitions, instead of CSS keyframe animations). This doesn't deserve any downvotes. Thank you, Ahmad.

Comment: Hi, link broken on your demo..please can you explain further in your example (full line of code), thx :)

Comment: @SébastienGarcia-Roméo did you find a solution for what you need ??